# TextField bottom overflowed when focused

Tags: flutter, overflow, textfield

I have `TextField` in Flutter. It is located at the bottom of the screen, example:
[image]

I placed few `Text`s before to move it to the bottom, for this example. When I focus `TextField`, overflowed area appears:

[image]

How to get rid of this area? One option would be to display keyboard (without overflowed area) or second to display "white screen" with text field like we are used in Android (in landscape, when there is not much place).

Can somebody advise, how to get rid of this faulty behaviour? Thank you.

My code:

```
return Scaffold(
  key: scaffoldKey,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("Test"),
        ...
        TextField()
      ],
    ),
  )
);
```

Comment: Try to wrap whole Column inside the ListView or Share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `Column` widget inside the `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView` to make it scrollable when keyboard open :

```
return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView(
            padding:EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Test"),
                  ...
                  TextField()
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  key: scaffoldKey,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Test"),
          ...
          TextField()
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```